# Using both time dependent covariates and time dependent coefficients in a Cox Model

Tags: survival, time-varying-covariate, proportional-hazards

In the context of a study, I am comparing two surgical interventions and I am interested in the time delay before the occurrence of a specific clinical event after surgery.

I have conducted a multivariate Cox model with adjustment for two time-dependent binary variables (variables that can change value during follow-up). These two variables were introduced into the model based on clinical assumptions. Prior to this, I ensured that my dataframe was formatted in the data count process format (using the function tmerge() in R).

A problem arises: the assumption of proportional hazards is not met for the variable related to the surgical intervention. My hypothesis (based on my clinical experience) is that the risk is higher in the immediate post-surgical period (< 1 month) compared to the late post-surgical period.

[image]

Is it possible to introduce both time-dependent effect variables (in this case, surgical intervention) and time-dependent variables into the same model? If yes, how can it be done?

It would be interesting to estimate different coefficients over different times intervals.
I have read that it can be done after formatting data with the function survSplit(). But I am not sure if I can use this function on my dataframe which is in a count process format.